# onclick gives me an error in html. how do I rectify this?

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to JS. In my index.html, I have a button defined as:

```html
<button id="copyPicture" onclick="copyPage();" class="btn">Copy Page!</button>
```

and in my script.js, I have:

```
function copyPage() {
    // Select the entire page
    var page = document.body;
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(page);
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  
    // Copy the selected page to the clipboard
    document.execCommand('copy');
  
    // Remove the selection
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  }
```

When I inspect the page in Chrome, as soon as I click on the button, I get:

(index):87 Uncaught ReferenceError: copyPage is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

What am I doing wrong?

When I click on the button, I am expecting the whole page to get copied to the clipboard so that I can paste it on emails, social medias, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error it looks like your JS is not properly included. `copyPage` function is not available when you click on the button. The snippet should work.

```js
function copyPage() {
    // Select the entire page
    var page = document.body;
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(page);
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  
    // Copy the selected page to the clipboard
    document.execCommand('copy');
  
    // Remove the selection
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  }
```

```html
<button id="copyPicture" onclick="copyPage();" class="btn">Copy Page!</button>

<p>Test text</p>
```

Comment: I have other functions in my JS file that get executed properly. Only this one seems to give me issues. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does order/placement of the code matter? Should it be in a script tag in my html file instead of the JS file?

Comment: It is hard to say as I don't see full snippet. It doesn't really matter if it is inlined in JS or in the file. However, it should be loaded before you click the button.

Comment: how do I make sure hat the function is loaded? I ask because when I moved the script below the button (enclosing it with a script tag), it worked.